# Call to a member function getAttributes() on null

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute, additional-information

I have a php code for creating a product feed **XML**, including all the additional attributes of the products. It worked fine until I upgraded from `1.9.3.1` to `1.9.3.4`.

After the upgrade my script gives this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getAttributes() on null in /www/new/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php on line 58.
```

My codepart which takes care of extracting the additional attributes:

```
        $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
        $add = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes();
        $add->setProduct($productId);
        $_additional = $add->getAdditionalData(); 

        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $_product->setStoreId($storeId);
        $_product->load($productId); 


        foreach ($_additional as $_data): 

        $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
            if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) !='') && (!is_null($_data['label'])) && (!is_null($_data['value'])))
        {
        $produs->appendChild($xml->createElement(str_replace(" ","_", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_ ]/", "",$_data['label'])), str_replace($replace_from, $replace_to, strip_tags($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])))));
        } 
        endforeach;
```

What has changed between the two versions and what should I modify in my code to make it work again?

Comment: I dont have your full code, but looking into the source of app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php it appears that   $product = $this->getProduct(); (from line 57) is not returning the product, backtracking to the getProduct() method, tells me that the product has not been set in the registry ie: Mage::registry('product');  returns NULL. Could you try with the following code and let me know if it helps https://gist.github.com/natrod/9c074cc70351c2cb4bcc8cb806faf0d8

Comment: You are perfectly right, your code is working like a charm, thank you!!

Comment: Adding as an answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the source of [app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.9.3.4/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View/Attributes.php) it appears that `$product = $this->getProduct();` (from line 57) is not returning the product, backtracking to the getProduct() method, tells me that the product has not been set in the registry ie: Mage::registry('product'); returns NULL.  You could try the following code to see if it fixes the issue.

```
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/output');
    $add = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes();
    $add->setProduct($productId);


    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $_product->setStoreId($storeId);
    $_product->load($productId); 


    Mage::register('product', $_product);
    $_additional = $add->getAdditionalData();

    foreach ($_additional as $_data): 

    $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
        if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) !='') && (!is_null($_data['label'])) && (!is_null($_data['value'])))
    {
    $produs->appendChild($xml->createElement(str_replace(" ","_", preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9_ ]/", "",$_data['label'])), str_replace($replace_from, $replace_to, strip_tags($_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code'])))));
    } 
    endforeach; 

    Mage::unregister('product');
```